# PrimeVue DataTable Column Sort not Working with Date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, datatable, primevue

I have a DataTable, as listed below:

```
<DataTable
  :rows = "5"
  :value = "apiItems"
>
  <Column
    :field="initialDate"
    :header="Initial Date"
    :sortable="true"
    />
    
    <Column
    :field="finishDate"
    :header="Finish Date"
    :sortable="true"
    />
</DataTable>
```

initialDate and finishDate are both data fields that are pulled from an API call, and will look something like this:
"08/21/2022 11:43:12"

When I attempt to sort these columns, they do not sort by the actual date (which is what I need), but just the first number in the string (which is the month)

WHAT IT DOES:

```
Ascending:
"08/22/2021 11:43:12"
"07/01/2022 12:01:09"
```

WHAT I NEED:

```
Ascending:
"07/01/2022 12:01:09"
"08/22/2021 11:43:12"
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED:
Attempted to turn the already present date into a JS Data object as such: new Date(initialDate).toLocaleString().
Doesn't sort properly still.

Thanks for the Assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort dates, you must be able to compare them, and the best way to do it is to convert them into **timestamps** *(number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC)*.

```js
const date1 = new Date('08/22/2021 11:43:12')
const date2 = new Date('07/01/2022 12:01:09')
```

You can retrieve the timestamp of a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) using either the [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method or a [unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

```js
console.log(date1.getTime()) // 1629603792000
console.log(+date2) // 1656648069000
```

**Ascending sorting**

Sorting is then quite easy using the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

```js
console.log([date1, date2].sort((a,b) => +b - +a))
```

---

###### Full example

```js
const date1 = new Date('08/22/2021 11:43:12')
const date2 = new Date('07/01/2022 12:01:09')

console.log([date1, date2].sort((a,b) => +b - +a))
```